# Don't hate the [player] hate the tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/player) tag feels like a classic meta tag, and one likely to be misused. I saw it in use for a question what seems to be a glorified cd player but could refer to audio, video or other software that plays things. Should we nuke it, or is there an arguement for fixing up the tag with proper tag wikis and stuff?

Comment: Looks like it can nuked and replaced with vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, flash-player, mp3-player etc as appropriate.

Comment: I read this title and could have sworn it would have been fixer1234's. Well done!

Comment: @Raystafarian, things are really in bad shape if my lame humor is the gold standard.  Unless what you meant is the lamer the better, and JMG managed to sink to my level.

Comment: this is merely the third lowest form of humour ;p

Comment: So, it's not even your final form!?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, [player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/player) is too meta.  What to do about it?

- On many questions, it's just decoration, duplicating a specific player tag.  Delete those.
- On some other questions, separate word tags are used in place of a specific player tag.  Replace those word tag collections with the appropriate tag.
- On some questions, it looks like it isn't actually about the player, so it's just decoration.  Delete those.
- On questions where the tag is appropriate, replace it with the dedicated tag if it exists.

That might cover all of the questions, or it could leave some stragglers.  **If** there is a bunch of single questions about non-mainstream players, do we want a tag for each or a better catch-all tag with wiki guidance?  Do we want one tag that covers both hardware and software?

Recommendation: clean up the questions covered by the bullets, above.  Then look at what, if anything, is left and decide on the best solution.

**Update:** The noise has been cleaned out.  There are 16 questions left.  Most refer to non-specific player software (many are off-topic requests for a product recommendation).  There are 4 or 5 that refer to non-mainstream players (one question each).

Comment: Cleared up the tags